# Looping Highcharts in yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

why is the chart looping not according to criteria?
the souce code :

$model = Kriteria::find()->all();

```
   foreach ($model as $kriteria) {
       foreach ($data_iku as $iku) {
          $b[]= ([
            'type'=> 'column', 
            'name' =>$iku['nama'],
            'data' => array((int)$iku['hasil'])
          ]);
      }
echo
                    Highcharts::widget([

                      //truncated code...
                   ]); 

    }
```

[image: how to appear like this?]

Comment: what's your question? what's your purpose?

Comment: my question is why is my loop chart indistinguishable by criteria. my goal is to display charts according to criteria.

Comment: where you call $data_iku.. please edit your answer with whole and completed code

Comment: Hi @Rendra, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data and yii2. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, there was an error in my tag. This code is already running, but there is an error for looping data. I want the data to appear on the graph for each criterion, but the data on the last graph appears all the criteria in one graph. how is the correct code to display the data for each criterion.

Answer (score 0):

this is code in controller :

```
$model = Kriteria::find()->all();
        foreach ($model as $kriteria) {

         $data_iku = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
              select DISTINCT iku.id as idiku,iku.nama as nama,(sum(fi.nilai_user)over (partition by iku.id)) / (count(iku.id)over(partition by iku.id)) as hasil
                FROM erp_iku iku 
                join erp_indikator as ind on ind.iku_id = iku.id
                join form_indikator as fi on fi.indikator_id = ind.id
                where fi.spmi_id = 2 and iku.kriteria_id = "'.$kriteria['id'].'"
                GROUP by iku.id, ind.id,fi.id
                ')
          ->queryAll();

          foreach ($data_iku as $iku) {
              $b[]= ([
                'name' =>$iku['nama'], 
                'data' => array((int)$iku['hasil'])
              ]);

              }
          }
```

this is code in view :

```
<?php 
             
            foreach($model as $kriteria) {

                echo "<h3>Kriteria ".$kriteria->urutan.": ".$kriteria->nama . "</h3>";

                 foreach ($data_iku as $iku) {
              
                  $b[] = [
                                'name' =>$iku['nama'], 
                                'data' =>[(int)$iku['hasil']]
                               
                            ];

              }

            echo HighCharts::widget([
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'chart' => [
                        'type' => 'bar',
                    ],
                    'title' => [
                        'text' => 'Kriteria',
                    ],
                    'yAxis' => [
                        'title' => [
                           'text' => 'Hasil',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'series' => $b

                ],
            ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller set array with specific key about kriteria:

```
$model = Kriteria::find()->all();
        foreach ($model as $kriteria) {

         $data_iku = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
              select DISTINCT iku.id as idiku,iku.nama as nama,(sum(fi.nilai_user)over (partition by iku.id)) / (count(iku.id)over(partition by iku.id)) as hasil
                FROM erp_iku iku 
                join erp_indikator as ind on ind.iku_id = iku.id
                join form_indikator as fi on fi.indikator_id = ind.id
                where fi.spmi_id = 2 and iku.kriteria_id = "'.$kriteria['id'].'"
                GROUP by iku.id, ind.id,fi.id
                ')
          ->queryAll();

          foreach ($data_iku as $iku) {
              $b[$kriteria['id']][]= [ //here set array only for specific criteria
                'name' =>$iku['nama'], 
                'data' => [(int)$iku['hasil']]
              ];

              }
          }
```

and in your view checkfor array with this key:

```
  <?php 
                 
     foreach($model as $kriteria) {
    
         echo "<h3>Kriteria ".$kriteria->urutan.": ".$kriteria->nama . "</h3>";
         $b = []; //set empty array if $data_iku[$kriteria->id] is not set
         if(isset($data_iku[$kriteria->id])){
             $b = $data_iku[$kriteria->id];
         }
    
         echo HighCharts::widget([
                  'clientOptions' => [
                        'chart' => [
                            'type' => 'bar',
                        ],
                        'title' => [
                            'text' => 'Kriteria',
                        ],
                        'yAxis' => [
                            'title' => [
                               'text' => 'Hasil',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'series' => $b
    
                    ],
                ]);
    }
```